# Limit has to be equilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is this

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ a $C^1$ function, and let a solution, $x(t)$ ,of  $\dot x=f(x) $ be such that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=\xi$$, then $f(\xi)=0$

$\\$

It is easy to achive this if n=1, we can use the mean value theorem, but the problem is that in higher dimension the mean value theorem can't guarantee equality. Hope you can help

Comment: It follows from the Barbalat's Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Barbalat's_lemma_and_stability_of_time-varying_systems

Comment: A more direct approach (but by contradiction): Suppose $f(\xi)\ne0$. Then the solution $\psi(\cdot)$ of the IVP $\dot{x}=f(x)$, $x(0)=\xi$, is not constant. Let $\psi(\tau)=\eta\ne\xi$ for some $\tau\ne0$. Then, by the continuous dependence on initial conditions, $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x(t+\tau)=\psi(\tau)=\eta$. Do you see a contradiction?